# Learning EJB and advantages

Tags: java, ejb, ejb-3.0

I would like to learn EJB and I am looking for some insights and inputs from others who are experts in EJB.

I would like to know the following as

```
1) What are the advantages of using EJB?
2) When do we have to use EJB?
```

If I am using JDBC for data fetching, writing and database validations from java, how can I effectevely use EJB?

As am planning to learn EJB, without using JPA, can I use EJB in web application?

any help is highly appreciable.

Regards

Comment: If anyone is tagging to close this post, kindly let me know the reason. Thanks

Comment: Proposed reasons appear to be that it's too broad/general. I'm not convinced personally, I think it's entirely reasonable to ask "Why EJB" - what with the horrible EJB2 stuff, the cleanup in EJB3.1, the CDI-provided alternatives, etc. Please **do not close**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1) What are the advantages of using EJB?

- dependency injection
- automatic life-cycle
- thread-safe out of the box
- automatic transaction demarcation
- simple AOP support
- easy deployment

> 2) When do we have to use EJB?

We don't *have to*, but it's a wise choice when implementing any sort of scalable server, typically accessed using HTTP (web, SOAP, REST)

> If I am using JDBC for data fetching, [...], how can I effectevely use EJB?

EJB container will inject `DataSource` for you to your EJB, from now on its up to you. EJB spec does not provide any support for plain JDBC, there is only JPA.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. So if I am using plain JDBC, then there is no point in using EJB isn't it. That means I need to use Hibernate of Toplink to take advantage of EJB's right? Could you suggest few online resources for EJB with JPA? Regards

Comment: @Polappan: well, your JDBC code will remain the same, but will be inside EJB, not inside `main()` method, no other support. The only help is automatic transaction management within EJB. As for resources, hate to be the person, but Google will provide plethora of nice tutorials. Just look for EJB 3.1 and JPA 2.0.

Comment: For simple usecases, injecting an entity manager and using it to excecute native SQL is easier and less verbose than using JDBC directly. So then too EJB has a (small) advantage.